# Can I speak Persian(other than English) in comments?

Tags: support, comment, languages

One person from Iran write a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565440/repeated-nodes-in-tree-decomposition-of-a-graph-is-allowed-or-not?noredirect=1#comment3187398_1565440) and there is no answer to it.
If we discuss in Persian may be I can understand better his problem and answer it.
Can I do it generally in comments, with Persian people?

Comment: Here's a proposal: how about providing an answer in Persian and a translation in English?  Then, after a set period (e.g., 1 week), the Persian is deleted and the English solution kept.  I only say this because this is an English-language site and not because I claim any superiority of English to Persian.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with having comments in Persian, especially if you think you might be able to help clarify the problem. Comments don't really have the same weight as questions & answers, so anything polite is likely to be appropriate to post.

Comment: I'd say if it significantly increases the chance of solving a problem, then it is fine to use  a language other than English. In the specific case, the English of OP seems just fine. I do not see the need to deviate from English.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral.  If a Question is need of clarification, and a request for clarification in English goes unanswered or gives equivocal information, a comment in another language attempting to bridge the divide could be helpful and (thus) worth trying.  Related: [Translation of Mathematical Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/translation-of-mathematical-questions) and the links there.

Comment: Minor note, if you have a long string of comments between the two of you at the question, in whatever language, the system will eventually request that the two of you move the discussion to a chat room, which it will create.

Comment: I have seen several cases where someone uses another language in comments to clarify something with the OP. In certain cases, particularly for unclear questions where the OP is having challenges with English, using another language seems like the best way to move things forward.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the comments to be in English. Note that math.SE is not just about question getting answered, but helping other users who are browsing that question, looking for answers. While use of Persian in the comments might make your communication easier with the OP and clarify a great deal to the OP, there are users who don't know Persian reading that post, and perhaps they'd miss some important clarification done in the comments (in Persian, say).

What you can do, on the other hand, is to post all the clarifications in English and discuss about them (in Persian, say) on the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). This wouldn't confuse readers of the post and you'd be able to clarify OP's doubts in their language too.

Comment: The suggestion to use in chat is only feasible if the OP has [at least 20 reputation points](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

Comment: The quest for 20 reputation is a barrier to entry to the chat system and using it as a lower bar for discussing/clarifying questions leaves users who are non-English or non-native English speakers with no real opportunity to meet that requisite (unless a question is so important/interesting that even as a poor translation earns the asker that 20 reputation).